# No message from IOutputHelper is shown with dotnet test command

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

xUnit has dropped the support for `dotnet xunit` package ([release notes](https://xunit.github.io/releases/2.4)).
I am using `IOutputHelper` and `dotnet xunit` to writes messages to the console during test execution in my .NET Core 2.1 project and 2.1.5 runtime version.

Moving away from that, there is no output from my test cases using `dotnet test --verbosity detailed`. How can i see those output from `IOutputHelper`?